# Existe alguma diferença entre "new" e "reinterpret_cast" para um buffer de memória?

Tags: c++, cast

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma diferença do produto final destes dois códigos :

```
//------ Declaração curta
class ClasseA {
public:
    int valor;
    Classe() { iniciar(); }

    ClasseA * iniciar() { valor = 10; return this; }
}

int main() {
  char * buffer1 = new char[sizeof(ClasseA)];
  char * buffer2 = new char[sizeof(ClasseA)];

  //Usando operador NEW
  ClasseA* ponteiro1 = new (buffer1) ClasseA();

  //Usando reinterpret_cast
  ClasseA* ponteiro2 = reinterpret_cast<ClasseA*>(buffer2)->iniciar();

  std::cout << "Ponteiro 1 : " << ponteiro1->valor << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Ponteiro 2 : " << ponteiro2->valor << std::endl;

  delete buffer1;
  delete buffer2;

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Tem um exemplo melhor? Que faça sentido e principalmente que não seja reticências. Este código não parece fazer sentido, então neste caso qualquer um dos não deveria sere usado.

Comment: @Maniero: A pergunta é muito boa e relevante, só achei que o exemplo de código deveria ser melhor elaborado, ficou difícil entender de primeira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, a diferença está na chamada do construtor do objeto `T`, que não acontece no caso do `reinterpret_cast`.

Quando você utiliza a palavra reservada `new` para inicializar um objeto `T` em um *buffer* pré-alocado (conhecido como [Placement Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)), `new` não faz nenhuma alocação de memória, ele somente realiza a chamada do construtor do objeto `T`, retornando o **mesmo** ponteiro do *buffer* pré-alocado.

Quando você utiliza `reinterpret_cast` "forçando" a conversão do ponteiro do *buffer* pré-alocado para um ponteiro que aponta para um objeto `T`, a chamada do construtor do objeto `T` não é realizada.

Em ambos os casos, o destrutor do objeto `T` **nunca** é chamado pois `delete` apenas libera a memória pré-alocada do *buffer* e não "conhece" o objeto `T`.

Segue um código funcional que ilustra a diferença entre as duas semânticas:

```
#include <iostream>

class Cachorro {
    public:
        Cachorro( void ) { std::cout << "Construtor" << std::endl; }
        virtual ~Cachorro( void ) { std::cout << "Destrutor" << std::endl; }
        void latir( void ) const { std::cout << "Au! Au!" << std::endl; };
};

int main(void) {
    //
    // placement_params
    //

    char * buf1 = new char[ sizeof(Cachorro) ];

    Cachorro * p1 = new(buf1) Cachorro;

    p1->latir();

    std::cout << "buf1: " << (void*) buf1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "p1: " << (void*) p1 << std::endl;

    delete [] buf1;

    //
    // reinterpret_cast
    //

    char * buf2 = new char[ sizeof(Cachorro) ];

    Cachorro * p2 = reinterpret_cast<Cachorro*>(buf2);

    p2->latir();

    std::cout << "buf2: " << (void*) buf2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "p2: " << (void*) p2 << std::endl;

    delete [] buf2;

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Construtor
Au! Au!
buf1: 0x94c010
p1: 0x94c010
Au! Au!
buf2: 0x94c010
p2: 0x94c010
```

**Referências:**

Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax

StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

cppreference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new